# adding slietoogle effect to a hide and show div

Tags: jquery, mouseover, slidetoggle, mouseout

Hello I'm using a javascript to hide or show a div.

here is the JS :

```
$(function() {

  $('#nav').css("height","9px");


   $('#nav').mouseover(function() {
       $('#nav').css("height","84px");
       $('.image_thumbnails').css("visibility","visible");

});
       $('#nav').mouseout(function() {
       $('#nav').css("height","9px");
       $('.image_thumbnails').css("visibility","hidden");


   });
});
```

so when mouseover the 9px height #nav, my #nav gets 84px height and the image_thumbnails get visible, and when mouseout back to 9px height and images hidden.

I would like to add animation to this code, like slideToogle...

for the div height and for the image opacity of visibilty
can anybody helps me with this ?

thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery Animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/),
try:

```
$(function () {
    // Cache nav for better performance
    $nav = $('#nav');
    // Same for thumbnails
    $thumbnails = $('.image_thumbnails');

    $nav.on('mouseenter', function () {
        // Use stop to clear the animation queue and jump to the end
        $nav.stop().animate({
            height: "84"
        }, "slow");
        $thumbnails.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, "slow");

    });
    $nav.on('mouseleave', function () {
        $nav.stop().animate({
            height: "8"
        }, "slow");
        $thumbnails.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PAw8q/4/)**

Comment: thanks @Johnny000, the animation is correct, but it keeps going up and down without stopping... do you know why ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your whole code / html

Comment: my code is simple... #nav, and inside #nav <li></li>, inside my li I have an image with <a href="#">... when mouseover outside the li it works fine, but when mouseover li it keeps going up and down, is it because of the href ?

Comment: I updated the answer and made a demo fiddle, if you like it consider to accept the answer.

Comment: one more question, when mouseover my #nav during the mouseenter and mouseleave height animation, it bugs, is it possible to complete the animation and block new animation until the animation is complete ? to test on the jsfiddle just hover the mouse on the #nav div and you'll see what I mean... thanks

Comment: It's caused because the stop() functions clears the wrong event/queue, you need to work with own queues for each animationelement. I'm at work right now and can't drop some fresh code

Comment: I found the solution, updated my answer and fiddle, upvote if you like it :)